# References for microlocal versions of some theorems

Tags: reference-request, microlocal-analysis

I am trying to introduce myself into Microlocal Analysis. In particular, motivated by some results in Inverse Problems, I would like to find good references for the **microlocal versions of Helgason and Holmgren theorems**, and also for the so-called **Kashiwara's watermelon theorem**.

Ultimately, I am interested in understanding injectivity for Radon transform with limited angle.

I am reading Hörmander's classic and a couple of papers by Jan Boman.

However still, I wonder whether there is something (like some lecture notes, or some modern book) more up-to-date where all these ideas had been written down more pedagogically.

Thanks for any help you may provide

Comment: Melrose used to have some lecture notes on his website that looked at conormal distributions with applications to Radon transforms.

Comment: Thanks, I have not heard about those ones. I'll check them out.

Comment: for general microlocal analysis, my lecture notes on arxiv are I think decent. Shubin's book is good.

Comment: Thanks Mark, but I cannot find those notes on arXiv under your name.

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9906155

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now see what the issue was. These notes are indexed by the name " M. S Joshi", and when I typed Mark Joshi other stuff appeared, but not this.